# General solution for $~{\mathrm d^2 y\over\mathrm d x}-2{\mathrm d y\over\mathrm dx}=x^2~$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to evaluate a general solution for the following ode.
$$
{\mathrm d^2 y\over\mathrm d x}-2{\mathrm d y\over\mathrm dx}=x^2
$$

**My tries**

$$\begin{align}
t^2-2t&=0\\
t(t-2)&=0\\
y&=C_1 e^{0x}+C_2e^{2x}\\
&=C_1+C_2e^{2x}
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
y&=Ax^2+Bx+C\\
y'&=2Ax+B\\
y''&=2A\\
2A-4Ax-2B&\not=x^2
\end{align}$$

I think that these ways have no work for the solution.

I need your help.

Comment: Try a cubic particular integral.

Comment: Owing to your advice, I think I got the general solution(I've written it at answer post).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$
{\mathrm d^2 y\over\mathrm d x}-2{\mathrm d y\over\mathrm dx}=x^2
$$

$$\begin{align}
y&=Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D\\
y'&=3Ax^2+2Bx+C\\
y''&=6Ax+2B\\
(6Ax+2B)-6Ax^2-4Bx-2C&=x^2\\
-6Ax^2+(6A-4B)x+2(B-C)&=x^2\\
\end{align}$$

$$
\begin{cases}
A=-{1\over 6}\\
B=-{1\over 4}\\
C=-{1\over 4}\\
D=\text{arbitrary constant}
\end{cases}\tag{1}
$$

$$\begin{align}
\therefore~y&=C_1+C_2e^{2x}-{1\over 6}x^3-{1\over 4}x^2-{1\over 4}x+D
\end{align}\\
y=C_2e^{2x}-{1\over 6}x^3-{1\over 4}x^2-{1\over 4}x+\underbrace{C_3}_{C_1+D}
$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Looks good. And notice you can combine $C_1$ and $D$ into a single constant.

Answer (score 1):

$$
y''-2y'=x^2 \Rightarrow y'-2y-\frac{x^3}{3} + c
$$
this is a linear first order differential equation.
$$\mu = ke^{\int -2dx} = ke^{-2x}$$
$$y = \frac{\int \mu.-\frac{x^3}{3}dx}{\mu}$$

$$\int -ke^{-2x}\frac{x^3}{3}dx = -\frac{k}{3}\int e^{-2x}x^3dx$$
integrate by parts repeatedly until you reach the following result:

$$I = \frac{1}{2}x^3e^{-2x}+\frac{3}{4}x^2e^{-2x}+\frac{3}{4}xe^{-2x}+\frac{3}{8}e^{-2x} + c$$
therefore:
$$y = -\frac{1}{6}x^3-\frac{1}{4}x^2-\frac{1}{4}x+C$$

Answer (score 0):

Let me add an alternative method to work out a particular solution based on algebraic manipulations of the differential operators. The particular solution to
$$ D (D-2) [y] = x^2, $$
where $D = \mathrm{d}/\mathrm{d}x$
can be formally written as
$$ y_p = \frac{1}{D(D-2)}[x^2] = \left[ -\frac{1}{2D}-\frac{I}{4} - \frac{D}{8} - \frac{D^2}{16} + O(D^3) \right][x^2]. $$
Where $D^{-1}$ is to be understood as an antiderivative operator and $I$ is the identity operator. Note that $D^s[x^2]=0$ for any integer $s \geq 3$. Thus,
$$ y_p = -\frac{x^3}{6} - \frac{x^2}{4} - \frac{x}{4} - \frac{1}{8}.$$
The $-1/8$ term can be absorbed into the homogeneous solution, as indicated above.

I hope this is not taken too seriously.